# Insert specific row of a table into same table ONCE only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing the below elements:

```
YEAR | MONTH | COMP | COMP_DESC   | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMP_SD     | CURR | METHOD | POSITION_STATUS
2021 | 2     | ABC  | ABC Company | Jake    | Sam    | 11-01-2021 | USD  |        | 
2021 | 5     | XYZ  | XYZ Company | Neo     | June   | 23-09-2021 | USD  | OPEN   | METH_004
```

The Result i need:

```
YEAR | MONTH | COMP | COMP_DESC   | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMP_SD     | CURR | METHOD | POSITION_STATUS
2021 | 2     | ABC  | ABC Company | Jake       | Sam       | 11-01-2021 | USD  |        | 
2021 | 5     | XYZ  | XYZ Company | Neo        | June      | 23-09-2021 | USD  | OPEN   | METH_004
2021 | 5     | XYZ  | XYZ Company | RP_Neo     | RP_June   | 24-09-2021 | USD  |        |
```

When POSITION_STATUS='METH_004' AND METHOD='OPEN', I need the specific row to be duplicated in the same table with change in date and change in name JUST ONCE. and when i re run the query i dont want any more duplication happening

Below is the Query i have written:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(YEAR, MONTH, COMP, COMP_DESC, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMP_SD, CURR)

SELECT T.YEAR, T.MONTH, T.COMP, T.COMP_DESC, CONCAT('RP_',FIRST_NAME) AS N1, CONCAT('RP_',LAST_NAME) AS N2, 
EMP_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day' AS NXT_DAY, T.CURR FROM Table1 T WHERE POSITION_STATUS='OPEN' AND METHOD = 'METH_004'

EXCEPT

SELECT T1.POS, T1.YEAR, T1.MONTH, T1.COMP, T1.COMP_DESC, T1.COST_CENTER 
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table T2
ON T1.YEAR=T2.YEAR
AND T1.MONTH=T2.MONTH
AND T1.COMP=T2.COMP
AND T1.COMP_DESC=T2.COMP_DESC
AND T1.CURR=T2.CURR;
```

Can anyone suggest me changes to the code to get the result. The above code runs without error. But the row is not replicated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, not images. Show the desired result for the sample data.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with `RP_` prefix. It is added in the query and removed in data.

Comment: Can anyone give me a solution

Comment: first time need 2 rows in given condition but next time this two rows r unique rows right? If it is then what will be the method and position status value when re run? do u insert data in same table?

Comment: hi, The METHOD and POSITION_STATUS will be the same... but i dont want anymore duplicate values